# on click funtion is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In following code i want to run a function when someone click on SELL button(first td) but on click function is not working. it says run function is not defined.

```
function runfunction() {
  alert("success");
}

sendRequest(); //call function
function sendRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax/ajax_buybtc"); ?>',
    success: function(result) {
      var jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
      $(".tab1 tr.tr1").remove();
      jsonResult.forEach(function(data) {
        var newTr = ""; // I delete the value to avoid double tr declaration
        newTr +=
          '<tr class="tr1"> <td onclick="runfunction()" style="text-align:center;"><a><span  class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>';
        newTr += "<td id='xbtc " + data.xbtc + "'>" + data.xbtc + "</td>";
        newTr += "<td id='xbtc " + data.rate + "'>" + data.rate + "</td>";
        newTr += "<td id='xbtc " + data.xpkr + "'>" + data.xpkr + "</td>";
        newTr += "</tr>";
        $(".tab1 > tbody:last-child").append(newTr);
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        sendRequest(); //this will send request again and again;
      }, 4000);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to define `runfunction()` in your JavaScript code.

Comment: can you run forEach on json objects?

Comment: if `runfunction` is defined inside a function scope, it will not be able in onclick handlers. never use onclick handlers.

Comment: @Luca It *will* since it is inside of the method it is calling, it will be again and again....

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: My guess is you have `runfunction` defined inside of a document ready wrapper and the method is not global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a click function after adding a class (here I added 'td-click') to the td and remove the onclick attribute from td

```
$(".tab1").on("click", ".td-click", function(){
   alert("success");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `onclick="runfunction()"` to `onclick="runfunction"`. 
Currently what's happening is that the `runfunction` is executed, and its return value is bound to the `onclick` event. You want the function itself to be bound, not its return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
newTr += '<tr class="tr1"> <td onclick="runfunction()" style="text-align:center;"><a><span  class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>';
```

move onclick to span tag

```
newTr += '<tr class="tr1"> <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span onclick="runfunction()"  class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>';
```

> https://codepen.io/bot_3310/pen/JajYyY